# How to disable Skype and Lync telephony providers for Dynamics CRM completely

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015, url-protocol

How can we **disable the Skype and Lync providers completely** from Dynamics CRM 2015 Online in either supported or unsupported way?

**What I have tried so far:**
 - Created my own link on phone number fields
 - Tried to locate any jQuery event handlers attached to the  element in the DOM
 - Assigned the blank event handler to *Mscrm.ReadFormUtilities.handlePhoneNumberClick* (Ref: http://crmtipoftheday.com/2014/05/15/how-to-block-click-to-call-in-crm/)

Still when I click on the phone number the Dynamics create a blank page and activates an inline phone call record.

[image]

And when I run

```
frames[0].$('#telephone1 div span a').click();
```

from browser console, it doesn't create a blank page or an inline phone call record.

**NOTE: This was not happening prior to CRM 2015 Update 1 or in Update 1 legacy form rendering.**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging action.js, formcontrols.js and global.ashx and try hitting several times I caught the point in Mscrm API that was opening a new window for default telephony providers (Skype/Lync).

This script disabled the default telephony completely. Use with caution and test carefully before deploying to production environment as this is not supported.

```
Mscrm.ReadFormUtilities.openPhoneClient = function () { return; }
```